# Which firefox web driver preference is to allow screen sharing?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Firefox Options Preferences to avoid pop ups for permissions such as microphone, video. But I want to avoid the pop up for screen sharing too. This is the code where i am setting the Firefox Options:

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("permissions.default.microphone", 1);
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("permissions.default.camera", 1);
```

So, as i mentioned before, the question is, what would be the preference to allow screen sharing of entire screen in Firefox Web Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need this:

```
firefoxOptions.SetPreference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", true);
```

Comment: Yes!, this works like a charm. Amazing how I couldn't find this option for every permission. Thanks for your answer.